# How to add class to only one element from v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

I have 2 v-for loops:

```
    <div class="fret-column" v-for="(fret, index) in frets" :key="index">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="fret">
          <span
            class="string"
            v-for="(string, index) in stringsNumber"
            :key="index"
            :string="string"
            @click="showDot(fret, string)"
          >
            <div class="dot"></div>
          </span>
        </div>
        <p v-if="fretNumberIsVisible">{{ index + 1 }}</p>
      </div>
      <span class="fret-line"></span>
    </div>
```

I have div with dot class on every string, but they are transparent and when I click on a single dot, I want to change background color on this element.

```
data() {
    return {
      frets: 10,
      stringsNumber: 6,
      fretNumberIsVisible: true,
      dotIsVisible: false,
    };
  },
```

```
showDot(fret, string) {
      this.dotIsVisible = !this.dotIsVisible;
      console.log("fret number:" + fret);
      console.log("string number:" + string);
    },
```

It works, but It change background color of all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `dotIsVisible` as object with fret and string instead of boolean, and if you want multiple selection save it in array:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      frets: 10,
      stringsNumber: 6,
      fretNumberIsVisible: true,
      dotIsVisible: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isSelected(fret, string) {
      return this.dotIsVisible.find(d => (d.f === fret && d.s === string)) ? 'dot' : ''
    },
    showDot(fret, string) {
      if (this.isSelected(fret, string)) {
        this.dotIsVisible = this.dotIsVisible.filter(d => {
          return (d.f !== fret || d.s !== string)
        })
      } else {
        this.dotIsVisible = [...this.dotIsVisible, {f: fret, s: string}]
      }
    },
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.dot {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="fret-column" v-for="(fret, index) in frets" :key="index">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="fret">
        <span
          class="string"
          v-for="(string, index) in stringsNumber"
          :key="index"
          :string="string"
          @click="showDot(fret, string)"
        > 
          <div :class="isSelected(fret, string)">{{string}}</div>
        </span>
      </div>
      {{dotIsVisible}}
      <p v-if="fretNumberIsVisible">{{ index + 1 }}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="fret-line"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It almost work the way I want, but when I click 2 elements, the first element dissapear

Comment: @Eryk Lange hey mate, check again pls, I updated my answer